# this.toPaddedString is not a function prototype

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, prototype

I get this error when using jQuery and prototype together. I wrote custom javascript for a shipping calculation module in magento and am unable to solve this error in firebug console. Anyone who knows a hint to solve this, please do write here.

```
TypeError: this.toPaddedString is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

return this.toPaddedString(2, 16);
```

Here is the JS iam using but didn't make any changes to the prototype, still the error emerges from the prototype.

```
( function($) {
        // we can now rely on $ within the safety of our "bodyguard" function
        $(document).ready( function() {

$('.s_code').change(function() {
 // remove all previous selections
 $('.option_all_box').attr('checked', false);
 $('.option_all').val('0');

 // hide all divs
 $('.option_top').hide();

 // show appropriate div & select first option
 if($(this).val() == 'A')
 {
 $('.option_s').fadeIn();
 $('.s_first').attr('checked', true);
 }
 else if ($(this).val() == 'B')
 {
 $('.option_p').fadeIn();
 $('.p_first').attr('checked', true);
 }

 });

 $('#frm_calculate').change(function() {
 // ajaxify the calculate
 // submit the form
 $('#totalship').html('Please wait, Recalculating...');
 formdata2 = $("form #frm_calculate").serialize();

var posting = $.post('calculate.php', formdata2, 'json');
posting.done(function( data ) {

//alert(data);
 if(data.error)
 {
 //$('#totalship').html("Error!");
    if(data.error.errorMessage == 'Please enter a valid amount.')
     {
     $('#totalship').html('Please enter a valid amount for extra cover (greater than zero)');
     }
     else
     {
     $('#totalship').html(data.error.errorMessage);
     }
 }
 else
 {
 var result = data.postage_result;
    thisqty = <?php echo $qtyArray[$i];?> ;
 str = result.service + '<br>' + result.delivery_time + '<br>' + result.total_cost*thisqty;

 // loop over the cost breakdown
 //alert($(result.costs.cost).size());
 listsize = $(result.costs.cost).size();

 str = str + "<table width='100%'>";
 if (listsize > 1)
 {
 $.each(result.costs.cost, function(key,value) {
 str = str +'<tr><td width="50%">'+ value.item + '</td><td width="50%" style="text-align: right;">$' + value.cost*thisqty + '</td></tr>';
 });
 }

 else if (listsize == 1)
 {
 value = result.costs.cost;
 str = str + '<tr><td width="50%">'+value.item + '</td><td width="50%" style="text-align: right;">$' + value.cost*thisqty + '</td></tr>';

 }
 //Get variable from javascript back into this file's PHP code
 var sendtoget1 = result.total_cost;
 var sendtoget = sendtoget1; //*thisqty
 var posting2 = $.post('sendtoget.php', sendtoget , 'text');
posting2.done(function( data ) {
//alert(data);
});

 str = str + "</table>";

 $('#totalship').html(str);
 $('#totalship').fadeIn();

 }


});
 });

 } );
    } ) ( jQuery );
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - this error comes from the extension of the Number Prototype inside the `toColorPart()` method (which is used to convert RGB colors to Hex colors). You don't seem to be using anything of the sort in the provided javascript. Can you trace the stack back to see the call that originated the error?

Comment: I don't see where you've used the `.toPaddedString` function on the second set of JS.. can you add more context to your problem? This is practically unsolvable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, but I got the same error but under a slightly different circumstances. My data was not formatted correctly when I was doing my ajax call. I ended up doing $.ajax(..., data: {key:value},...) and it ended up working.

This was the top post that came up when I googled the error, so I figured I should share incase someone else is in the same situation.